# How can I stop Firefox from hanging after clicking a link?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, skype

Webdriver with Python bindings v2.39.0
Firefox 27.0 (but issue also reproduced with Firefox 'latest', Firefox 26.0 and Firefox 27.0)

In the code below, once the execution hits `obj.click()` for links on a certain page, the browser hangs. If the script is killed with Ctrl+C in the terminal (Windows), the browser stops hanging. If left to it's own devices, the browser will seem to hang indefinitely.

I'm not sure if I am allowed to post the HTML for the problem page but I may be able to negotiate it with my team.

This very same code used to work perfectly with the very same element that is causing problems now. I had suspected it was something to do with the auto upgrade Firefox but downgrading has not solved the issue (please see things I have tried section for more details and things I have tried)

```
def wait_and_click(obj_id, timeout=global_timeout, locator_attribute = 'ID'):
    print('waiting for ' + obj_id)
    obj = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((eval('By.' + locator_attribute), obj_id)))
    print("about to click object")
    obj.click()
    print("about to return from wait_and_click")
    return obj
```

Things I have tried:

- manually replicating the issue (no browser hang)
- tried downgrading to different versions of firefox and uninstalling all extensions
- tried skipping the obj.click when if the obj_id equals the problem element - browser doesn't hang (but the script doesn't go anywhere :p because something needs to be clicked)
- tried a more conventional WebDriverWait for an element on the page
  and then find_element_by_xpath - same browser hang
- tried locating the element by a different attribute (initially tried using LINK_TEXT, also tried via XPATH - no difference) and then clicking
- tried finding different links on the same page - same browser hang
- tried finding links on different pages of the same web app - no browser hang
- tried saving the source of the page containing the link and of th page the link points to. I got webdriver to open the local copy of the page and click on the problem link - the destination page opened with no browser hang

Comment: Does the object exist when you do the click? Because there's a timeout on the wait, and if it hits the timeout you might pass there without having the object (I'm guessing).

Comment: if it hits the timeout, wouldn't I get a ElementNotFound or a TimeoutException error? Or something similar that would cause the execution to terminate (not the browser to stop working?) Also, I know it is getting to obj.click because "about to click object" is printing to the console.

Comment: You're right, according to the documentation it should throw an exception if it doesn't find the element. Have you tried manually replicating the issue (just clicking the element in the browser, or trigger a click via the console)? As for posting the html or not, you could start by stripping as much from the page as possible, that will help narrow down the problem and make it less of a issue if you do need to share the html.

Comment: yeah, I have tried manually reproducing the issue and the issue does not manifest. I have added it to my "things I have tried" list. Good idea with stripping the html :) I never done that before. I guess I could save the page source and get webdriver to open a local copy of the source and experiment from there. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: whether it was what you had in mind or not, I tried running the pages locally and the link worked fine. So it looks like it has something to do with an interaction between the way the app server is serving the pages and webdriver. But I have no idea what to do next

Answer (score 1):

Argh, this is such a frustrating solution - it seems it was because of the Skype toolbar that was automatically installed with the latest Firefox upgrade.

It's worth noting that it will not go away easily. If you go to Firefox -> Extensions, it only allows you to disable it. You have to go to 'Programs and Features' and uninstall it from there. After that, it worked like a charm!

FFS MICROSOFT!!